# Openstack create user without keystone authentication

Tags: openstack

I want to add "Resgister" for Openstack. So, I want to create user without keystone authentication. Could someone tell me how to do it ? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you backend keystone to LDAP you could use any LDAP management interface.  Alternatively you can directly manipulate the mysql database.  However in the mysql scenario you'd probably want to setup a binlog and follow what keystone does when you do a user create from keystone client then replicate those queries with dynamic data identified and filled.