# Openstack create a super user like admin

Tags: openstack

I am trying to add register to Openstack. So I want to create a super user like admin. Then I can create user by the super user without Admin. Could someone give me some advice ?

Answer (score 2):

I responded to your previous question about alternative ways to control user management in openstack.  Using the keystone API there aren't many options at the moment though, adam young is doing a lot of work on implementing shared trusts in tokens.  This will provide the means to grant a trusted token to a user for a reduced set of administrative functionality... eventually.  For now though you are probably better looking at the solutions I put forth in your other stack overflow question.

ref: [Openstack create user without keystone authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971893/openstack-create-user-without-keystone-authentication)

You can read more about trusts and rbac in openstack here:  http://adam.younglogic.com/2013/03/trusts-rbac/

Below is how you create a user who is not 'admin' but has an admin role

You can use this to create a user that can be used by your code to create new users.  However, obviously that code will have full administrative credentials.  I don't know what your risk profile is.  But obviously you want to be able to register users.  You might consider building a simple RPC mechanism with a keystone admin cred.  And have your public facing app send minimal info to that RPC service.  Then harden the RPC interface.  Or, as I said before, consider the alternatives suggested in your other stackoverflow question ( IE: LDAP, direct MySQL queries )

```
root@openstack-cc1:~# keystone tenant-list
+----------------------------------+----------+---------+
|                id                |   name   | enabled |
+----------------------------------+----------+---------+
| 5c1bd4f84d044450aaa22d16360f29c0 |  admin   |   True  |
| 2862b9e419b74880a507f96de3424f89 | services |   True  |
+----------------------------------+----------+---------+
root@openstack-cc1:~# keystone user-create --name sallyadmin --tenant-id 5c1bd4f84d044450aaa22d16360f29c0 --pass sallypassword --email sally@cloudbadass.net --enabled true
+----------+----------------------------------+
| Property |              Value               |
+----------+----------------------------------+
|  email   |      sally@cloudbadass.net       |
| enabled  |               True               |
|    id    | ac822a0297864fe6870b065e50ea4568 |
|   name   |            sallyadmin            |
| tenantId | 5c1bd4f84d044450aaa22d16360f29c0 |
+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Now you should have a user sallyadmin in that admin tenant.

Now lets add a role

```
root@openstack-cc1:~# keystone role-list
+----------------------------------+----------+
|                id                |   name   |
+----------------------------------+----------+
| b3dc33d067a240d49b5c1404fee049f1 |  Member  |
| 9fe2ff9ee4384b1894a90878d3e92bab | _member_ |
| ba82a9493b034d4b83ae96c8aff75b8d |  admin   |
+----------------------------------+----------+
root@openstack-cc1:~# keystone user-list
+----------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+
|                id                |    name    | enabled |         email          |
+----------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+
| ccf2c111e21c44dca0ab40f6a886247c |   admin    |   True  | matt.joyce@lulz.com    |
| 5e82674cc67d461c9a3ccb14e86b3794 |   cinder   |   True  |    cinder@localhost    |
| 80d8defdf0464787b11423427c0fe508 |   glance   |   True  |    glance@localhost    |
| 8332b99589044cd5a40ca1a9329f7aef |    nova    |   True  |     nova@localhost     |
| ac822a0297864fe6870b065e50ea4568 | sallyadmin |   True  | sally@cloudbadass.net  |
+----------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+
root@openstack-cc1:~# keystone user-role-add --user ac822a0297864fe6870b065e50ea4568 --role ba82a9493b034d4b83ae96c8aff75b8d --tenant-id 5c1bd4f84d044450aaa22d16360f29c0
```

Now lets test out sallyadmin!

```
root@openstack-cc1:~# export OS_USERNAME="sallyadmin"
root@openstack-cc1:~# export OS_PASSWORD="sallypassword"
root@openstack-cc1:~# keystone user-list
+----------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+
|                id                |    name    | enabled |         email          |
+----------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+
| ccf2c111e21c44dca0ab40f6a886247c |   admin    |   True  | matt.joyce@lulz.com    |
| 5e82674cc67d461c9a3ccb14e86b3794 |   cinder   |   True  |    cinder@localhost    |
| 80d8defdf0464787b11423427c0fe508 |   glance   |   True  |    glance@localhost    |
| 8332b99589044cd5a40ca1a9329f7aef |    nova    |   True  |     nova@localhost     |
| ac822a0297864fe6870b065e50ea4568 | sallyadmin |   True  | sally@cloudbadass.net  |
+----------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should use python code to realize "create  a user like admin", not the "shell mode" now. I think I should create a keystoneclient like this "keystone = client.Client(username='admin',
                         password='47da55c1e21f4360',
                         tenant_name='admin',
                         auth_url='http://10.0.3.181:35357/v2.0/')"                   ,but I don't know how to do it next. :-(

Comment: You say "You might consider building a simple RPC mechanism with a keystone admin cred. And have your public facing app send minimal info to that RPC service. " Could you tell me detailed steps to realize it?Thanks!

Comment: I have solved this question. I has installed Openstack G. I edit this file "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/api/keystone.py", add "def super_keystoneclient(request, username, admin=False)" like keystoneclient